# Xbox 360 restarts when switching TV Inputs (HDMI)

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

This has bothered me for some time.  My Xbox is hooked up to my TV through an HDMI cable.  Whenever I switch inputs (whether to another HDMI input or component) and then switch back to the Xbox, the Xbox restarts.  This makes it impossible to flip back and forth between a TV show and the Xbox for example.

Is this normal?  If not, are there any workarounds?

**What I've Tried**

- I have already tried different HDMI ports on the TV itself.
- When hooked up to the TV, other HDMI devices don't exhibit this behavior (PS3 for example)

**What I Haven't Tried Yet**

- I could try a different cable but I'd have to borrow it...  Would a cable defect explain this?

Comment: Have you tried swapping cables and/or sockets on the TV?

Comment: Should have added that...  Edited

Comment: I've also noticed that, when hooked up through HDMI, the Xbox won't actually go through the booting up animations until the TV is turned on.  You can turn the Xbox on and then the TV like five minutes later and it will start as if it were just turned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question on the official Xbox forums.  Do you use the adapter shown at the very bottom?  If so that might be what causes the issue.
http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/7/p/191396/996508.aspx#996508

See in this second post where Jaxson 66 mentions that if you are using the optical out for headphones, then swapping back to HDMI will cause the reset.
http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/7/p/191396/996508.aspx#996508

So in summary, you can "fix" the problem by disconnecting your headphones if switching between inputs when one of those inputs in HDMI.  This doesn't really fix your problem, but at least you can work around the issue until they push an Xbox fix or you can get a firmware update on your display.

Answer (score 4):

Something similar was happening to me on a Samsung LN630 model. The xbox would reset while watching netflix. The solution turned out to be upgrading the TV's firmware. Something over the HDMI interface seems to trigger a reset of the xbox.

Answer (score 3):

If you disconnect the the Xbox from the TV, does the same thing happen?  If so, I'd suspect a power supply problem.  Perhaps when it switches channels, the TV draws a large enough amount of power from a shared outlet or power strip to cause the Xbox to restart.